# Weird issue: Two SATA disks mutually incompatible?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, sata

I have a Linux system with three SATA HDs. Two of them seem to be incompatible with each other. I've never heard of that with SATA disks but here it is:

One drive is a Western Digital 160 GB disk, the other a Toshiba 500 GB one. When I install either of them I can see the partitioning correctly. (fdisk shows the correct size, and subdivision of the disk).

But, if I install both of them, fdisk doesn't see the partitioning any more, and reports wrong sizes on both drives.

This is with the third disk as a boot disk where the operating system is installed. I also tried to remove the OS disk, and put an OS on the 160 GB disk, but, as soon as I insert the Toshiba, the system won't mount the drives anymore during the boot sequence. (complains about not finding the superblocks anymore. Running e2fsck on the drive shows thousands of problematic inodes, until I remove the other drive)

The computer is an IBM X3200 server and should accommodate up to 5 hard drives. It shouldn't be a power problem. Linux distro is Slackware 14.2, and kernel is 4.4.4.

Does anyone suspect a cause for this problem?

Comment: When you have multiple disks in, what does sudo hdparm -i /dev/XXX show for the devices.  Also, what does "dmesg" show with respect of the hard drives.    I wonder if the issue could relate to having the same UUID on the drives (if you did a bit copy of one to the other maybe), or re-ordering / udev confusion.

Comment: @davidgo hdparm doesn't work - not with /dev/sda nor with /dev/sda1 (which would be incorrect anyway). *sdparm* does work, and gives different (and correct) data for each of the drives. Is the hex string at the end the UUID? They're different too. BTW, I initialized the drives separately - they're not bit copies.

Comment: Never used sdparm before now.  On my system it does not show the UUID, it does show a 4 letter ID though.  You should be able to see the UUID's and what they link to with ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid  (But I've not used Slackware for many, many years)

Comment: @davidgo Thanks - ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid works, but the UUIDs are different for all disks. The codes are also different from the hex value sdparm. I'm way behind on my project thanks to this problem, so I'm going to opt for leaving the 160G disk out for the moment. In a couple of days, I'll test the disk on another server at the university. I'm still inclined to suspect a problem on that particular disk.